# Select another user from same table

Tags: sql

So I have a table with users

A few users are "owners" 
A user can have a owner

Now I want to select the owner from the user (Both in the same table)

Example:
Owner:

```
user_id: 34
user_name: hiimowner
user_owner_id: NULL
```

User:

```
user_id: 63
user_name: randomperson
user_owner_id: 34
```

Now I'm looking for the proper SQL query to be able to find the user_name of the owner

So if I can request the owner of "randomperson" which should return "hiimowner"

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If yes, please share it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table AS t1
JOIN table AS t2
ON t1.user_id = t2.user_owner_id
WHERE t2.user_id = 63
```

Comment: This results gives me back 2 user_names my own and the owner
How do I get the 2nd one only from my result? $result['user_name']

Comment: **SELECT t2.user_id, t2.user_name, t2.user_owner_id, t1.user_id AS owner_user_id, t1.user_name AS owner_user_name, t1.user_owner_id AS owner_user_owner_id FROM ...** the rest is the same. Or simply **SELECT t2.* FROM ...** might also do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

try this,

```
Select u.*,o.user_name from User as u
left join  User o on o.user_id = u.user_owner_id
```

If want to filter specific record then add where clause,

```
Select u.*,o.user_name from User as u
left join  User o on o.user_id = u.user_owner_id
where u.user_id = 63
```

Comment: Owner is not a table. Owners are users and are stored in the User table.

Comment: Yes, now I got that, I am changing my ans.

Answer (score 3):

The trick you're looking for is a self join:

```
SELECT o.username
FROM   users o
JOIN   users u ON u.user_owner_id = o.user_id
WHERE  u.user_name = 'randomperson'
```

Comment: Both this and blue answer are correct, but it is always better to name table alias with an explicit name - and "o" is a better name than "t2" to name the Owner alias.